# A crossword puzzle

Tags: knowledge, crosswords

Here's a crossword puzzle. Can you solve it?

[image]

***CLUES***

> ACROSS

2) Wolfram

5) Between stars

8) 333 - Cricket

10) Play and eat

11) 400 not out

> DOWN

1) The boy who got a watch from a comet

3) Nanotubes

4) Forest and shopping

6) ICC WC 2019 teams

7) First to cross heliopause

9) Penalty

10) A math and puzzle lover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ACROSS
```

2) Wolfram

> Tungsten

5) Between stars

> Interstellar

8) 333 - Cricket

> Chris Gayle (from @jafe in comments)

10) Play and eat

> Dominos (from OP in comments) donairs? *[wrong, as mentioned by OP in comments]*

11) 400 not out

> Brian Lara?

```
DOWN
```

1) The boy who got a watch from a comet

> Ben?

3) Nanotubes

> Graphene (previous: Graphite)

4) Forest and shopping

> Amazon *[sidenote: nice clue!]*

6) ICC WC 2019 teams

> Ten(from @jafe in comments)

7) First to cross heliopause

> Voyager 2

9) Penalty

> Yellow

10) A math and puzzle lover

> Deusovi

Comment: +1 for the last one

Comment: 8 across is probably rot13([Puevf Tnlyr](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/cricket/9193836.stm))?

Comment: ...making 6 down rot13(gra)

Comment: @jafe Yes!!!! Both are correct!